# How much would Earth's temperature change if days were 28 hours long?

Tags: planets, weather

I know it would be colder at night and hotter during the day, but by how much? And it would impact atmospheric pressure, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

### Negligibly

Earth's day was about [21 hours in the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation#In_rotational_speed), and it will, eventually, be 28 hours millions of years from now.  The temperature of the planet as a whole is a function of energy delivered, and since rotation does not affect Earth's cross-section, that will not change.

Because Earth has a substantial atmosphere, nights will not be appreciably colder, nor days appreciably warmer.

It will also not appreciably impact atmospheric pressure, as atmospheric pressure is a function of the [mass of gasses in the atmosphere and the gravity of the planet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79690/calculating-atmospheric-pressure-on-an-imaginary-planet).  The atmosphere would bulge a little less near the equator, but pressures would remain the same.  (Since if there were an area of low pressure, areas of higher pressure would naturally flow into it.)

So the effects (other than those on someone used to a 24-hour day) would be pretty limited.